# TDD: Test first or Repository pattern first

Tags: tdd, repository-pattern

I'm new to TDD and I have a question with concept.
It's said in TDD no code is written without writing test first.
We usually need Repository pattern to mock objects and to be able to implement testing.
My question is: should we first implement Repository pattern ?
If yes,  what happens to writing test first ?
If no, how can we mock objects without using Repository pattern ?

I would appreciate your taking time.

Comment: Can't you wait to implement repository after writing a test?  Maybe you should add a code example for clarity.

Comment: I was wondering according to TDD concept which one I should implement first.If I don't implement Repository first I will have many problems for testing. from another hand in TDD it's said no code first.

Comment: What are the 'many problems' that you feel you will encounter?

Comment: Fro example for testing business logic I will be forced to connect to data model and database directly.But with having Repository I'm able to mock them.

Comment: So, why is that a problem for writing a test?  You would write the test `as if` the repository exists.  Broken compilation is the first fail.

Comment: That's my point. Is it right to start testing and connecting to database directly without mocking?

Comment: Btw, the Repository implementation should be one of the LAST things to do in an app. You app (and first the tests) should work properly with a fake,in memory implementation. That's the point of the pattern to decouple the persistence from the rest of the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you intend to develop using TDD there is no doubt that you have to create your tests first.

It will let you implement the repository pattern naturally and will make your life easier as the repository pattern will make unit testing less painful.

Even the TDD test cycle enforces this order:

1. Write a failing acceptance test
2. Write a failing unit test
3. Make the failing test pass
4. Refactor
5. Repeat steps 2-4 until the failing acceptance test passes

The repository pattern would be introduced in steps 3 and 4. when you actually write your code.

While I prefer those patterns to be introduced in step 4, some other people would just jump ahead and implement it in step 3. It's a matter of style, but I prefer the more complex code to be introduced once the unit test passes.

If you want to get a deeper understanding of this topic, there are some formidable books about refactoring, but one might be especially interesting for you as it logically binds refactoring and design patterns. [Refactoring to Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321213351)

I have implemented the repository pattern in TDD development myself a few months ago and it worked out just fine.

I think this is an excellent question, so thanks a lot for asking it.